# SQL Data Loader

Tags: sql-server, loader

Currently I'm developing the database in sql server. I have nearly 100 tables. I need to dump some sample data to the tables, so that I can test the stored procedures. Any tools is there to do this. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

The standard tools for bulk importing of data are the [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx), the (almost) equivalent [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) command and the [Import/Export wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) which can be accessed by a database's context menu in Management Studio. The wizard creates an SSSIS package behind the scenes that can be customized to modify data or iterate over a set of source files.

Comment: I dont have any source files to fill the tables as of now.. I need to fill the tables with some dummy values with satisfied with the data type of the columns. is this wizard can do this

Comment: Visual Studio Premium and above has a test data generator for database projects, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193262.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GenerateData.com](http://www.generatedata.com/#generator) to generate SQL insert statements.